# HTML Page cannot view using FLASK - got 404 error

Tags: python, html, json, flask, vis.js

I able to browse to my main page, index.html page using flask but when I click button on index page, the page is directed to mytopo.html page but no topology view appear and getting error. I'm getting error below when try to go to mytopo.html page. Seems it cannot find my json file (mytopo.json)

```
192.168.56.1 - - [16/Jan/2020 11:31:15] "GET /mytopo HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.56.1 - - [16/Jan/2020 11:31:15] "GET /mytopo.json HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

This is the structure of flask project

```
mywebfolder
  myapp.py --- main file and run server
  static --- for images
   image1.jpg
  templates --- all html files are here
   index.html
   mytopo.html
  data --- my json file is store here
   mytopo.json
```

myapp.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

#Function for index page
@app.route('/')
def startPage():
    bodyText=Markup("<b>MAIN PAGE</b>")
    return render_template('index.html', bodyText=bodyText)

#topology view
@app.route('/mytopo')
def mytopo():
    return render_template("mytopo.html")
```

index.html

```
<button style="width:10px;height:10px"><font size="6"><a href="mytopo">Topology View</a></font></button>
```

mytopo.html is to view the topology using vis.js and json file (mytopo.json)

```
var json = $.getJSON("mytopo.json")
  .done(function(data){
    var data = {
      nodes: data.nodes,
      edges: data.edges
    };
    var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
  });

var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');

</script>
```

I really appreciate someone could lead me the way...Please help and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you don't have the route to serve your JSON file. In your case, you have to create a new view function to serve your JSON data with the URL rule `/mytopo.json`:

```py
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/mytopo.json')
def mytopo_json():
    return send_from_directory(app.root_path, 'data/mytopo.json')
```

(The code wasn't test yet, if it doesn't work just let me know)

Comment: Hi...I will test it and update the outcome...thanks